Newton raphson method in multidimension space
I have a question, and that is, lets say $e(w) = x - x* = w^T\phi - x^* \in \mathbb R^n$, where $w \in \mathbb R^{N\times n}$ and $\phi \in \mathbb R^N$ I wish to use Newton Raphson method to find the solution of $e(w)=0$, i.e., what $w$ that will make $e\to 0$.
Now, if I use conventional NR method, I get the following:
$w_{i+1} = w_i - \frac{J(w)}{\nabla J(w)}$,
where, $J$ is defined as a scalar cost i.e., $J = \frac{1}{2}e^Te$.
I could clearly see that, $J(w) = \frac{1}{2}(x^{*T}x^*-x^{*T}w^T\phi-\phi^Twx^*+\phi^Tww^T\phi)$
Now, My main concern is,
(1) How should I analytically compute $\nabla_w J(w)$ ?
(2) What will be its dimension?
For simplicity, let, $n = 2$, and $N = 10$ and $x^*$ is available.
PS: I tried deriving the term and it comes out something like this:
$\nabla_w J(w)=\frac{1}{2}(-2x^*\phi^T + \phi^Tw\phi)$, but the dimension of the second term doesnt make sense! On the other hand, if we reorganize the second term as, $\phi\phi^Tw$, then it becomes dimensionally consistent i.e., $\nabla_w J(w) \in \mathbb R^{n\times N}$.
Now, the question arises, what will be its invertibility? Do I need to modify the NR as follows:
$w_{i+1}=w_i - (\nabla J \nabla J^T)^{-1}\nabla J* J(w)$
Am I doing it correct? Please shed some light. Thanks :)
